# What is the term to describe an improvement of $X$ to $\ln(X)$?

Tags: logarithms, terminology

Let's assume that $X$ represents the cost of a certain action. Now, we have an ingenious solution that drives the cost down to $\ln(X)$.

How do you call that? Logarithmic improvement? Or something else?

Comment: I think there is a name for improving complexity from $\mathcal{O}(n)$ to $\mathcal{O}(\ln n)$ or similarly. Don't know what though.

Comment: I just say you reduced the cost from linear to logarithmic in $X$.

Comment: @Rahul need something catchier